# Anyone knows how to insert special characters with color in url site title?

Tags: html, url, special-characters, symbols, titlebar

anyone knows how to insert special characters with color in url site title? Please take a look to the attached screen shot: 
https://www.screencast.com/t/l1SeqWgRW4

thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was actually punycode that enabled the conversion of URL to emoji.
**Punycode** is a representation of Unicode with the limited ASCII character subset used for Internet hostnames. [emojis display urls google search results](http://www.thesempost.com/emojis-display-urls-google-search-results/)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do place the special character or emoji in the title tag

```
<title> This is a title  </title>
```

you can copy and paste from https://getemoji.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's done by using Unicode characters. You can find an extensive list of them on this site: https://unicode-table.com/en/.

Just simply copy and paste them in your `<title>` tag like this:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
</html>
```